# Tensorflow MaxPool doesn't accept float64

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow to train a CNN. I am currently basing my calculations on Float32 which is kind of default at the time of initialising variables.

I guessed that by using `float64`as my dtype I can get more accurate results so I changed the initilization of my varibales as follows:

```
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 64], stddev=0.1, dtype=tf.float64))
```

But I get following error in the `maxpool`operation:
I chacked the `maxpool`documentation and it accept value type as follow:
`value: A 4-D Tensor with shape [batch, height, width, channels] and type float32, float64, qint8, quint8, qint32.`

But I get the following error. Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

`Input 'input' of 'MaxPool' Op has type float64 that does not match expected type of float32.`

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hamedketabdar/LearningTensorFlow/CIFAR-Khodam/convolutional_network_batch_2d2c_clean_64f.py", line 213, in <module>
    pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)
  File "/Users/hamedketabdar/LearningTensorFlow/CIFAR-Khodam/convolutional_network_batch_2d2c_clean_64f.py", line 153, in conv_net
    conv1 = max_pool(conv1, k=2) # Normally K=2
  File "/Users/hamedketabdar/LearningTensorFlow/CIFAR-Khodam/convolutional_network_batch_2d2c_clean_64f.py", line 135, in max_pool
    return tf.nn.max_pool(img, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1], padding='SAME')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 235, in max_pool
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 449, in _max_pool
    strides=strides, padding=padding, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 430, in apply_op
    (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))
TypeError: Input 'input' of 'MaxPool' Op has type float64 that does not match expected type of float32.
```

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/547

Comment: I opened myself this issue

Comment: Thanks. I added the link so that others could find it. Not everyone knows to look there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for `tf.nn.max_pool()` for types other than single-precision floating point values is currently not implemented, and the documentation is incorrect. (I have updated it upstream, and it should appear on GitHub and the website soon.)

The reason for the incompatibility is that TensorFlow has a [specialized implementation of max-pooling](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/maxpooling_op_gpu.cu.cc) on GPUs for performance reasons, and we almost always use `tf.float32` when training deep networks, so there isn't equivalent support for the other types. It would be possible to add, so contributions are welcome: see the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/547) for more discussion.

Comment: That's a pity. Not only the documentation was fooling me, too (saying `tf.nn.max_pool()` allows `tf.float64`) but also the little interest in 64bit floats. I am not too experienced but I would expect (for really big/deep networks) 64bit floats to produce nicer results in less training epochs because of the much higher precision?!